# How do I pass an anonymous function to map()?

Tags: kotlin

I'm working through a little code challenge in Kotlin.

> Write a function that nests the elements of a list one level deeper by repeating that
> element inside a new list a given number of times.
> Examples

> (nest [:a :b :c] 2) ;=> ((:a :a) (:b :b) (:c :c))

> (nest [] 10) ;=> ()

> (nest [1 2 3 4] 1) ;=> ((1) (2) (3) (4))

> (nest [1 2 3] 0) ;=> (()()())

I implemented `nest` like so:

```
fun <R> nest(list: List<R>, repeat: Int) =
    list.map{
        mem -> generateSequence(1) { it }
                .map { mem }
                .take(repeat)
                .toList()
    }
```

However, I'm wondering how I'd write the lambda as a separate anonymous function, which I'd pass to `map`, like...

```
val anonFunction = ???
list.map(anonFunction)
```

I'm not sure how this would work syntactically.

Comment: The notation in your initial examples is not Kotlin, and could do with some explanation.  But since the code challenge isn't relevant to your actual question, maybe the examples aren't needed at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curly braces is what starts a lambda function in Kotlin. The only thing you need to do to assign an arbitary lambda to a `val`, is to let Kotlin know what type it has.

This is probably the simplest way to do it. I am giving the compiler the type of the parameter, but letting type inference take care of the return type.

```
fun <R> nest(list: List<R>, repeat: Int): List<List<R>> {
    val anonFunction = { mem: R -> 
        generateSequence(1) { it }
            .map { mem }
            .take(repeat)
            .toList()
    }

    return list.map(anonFunction)
}
```

You could also do it by specifying the full function type of `anonFunction` by declaring it like this:

```
fun <R> nest(list: List<R>, repeat: Int): List<List<R>> {
    val anonFunction: (R) -> List<R> = { mem -> 
        generateSequence(1) { it }
            .map { mem }
            .take(repeat)
            .toList()
    }

    return list.map(anonFunction)
}
```

Side note:

A simpler implementation of your challenge could be this:

```
fun <R> nest(list: List<R>, repeat: Int) = list.map { elem ->
    List(repeat) { elem }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't compile. `Unresolved reference: R` and `Unresolved reference: repeat`.

Comment: @fungusAmongUs If you put it inside your `nest` function, it will compile. I edited the question with that. If you want to use it outside the `nest` function, then switch `R` to the type of the elements in your list and switch `repeat` to how many times you want it repeated.

Comment: Ok I understand your point. But what if I wanted `anonFunction` outside but I wanted it generic and I didn't know how many times I'd need to repeat it? Would I need to pass the function to `nest`? Lastly, thanks for the simpler solution. I didn't know you could do that with `List` so I went a hackier route

Comment: @fumgusAmongUs Kotlin does not support lambdas that take type parameters. But you could create another generic function that returns a new function specialized at the generic type.